# How can I stretch an image when swiping it

Tags: android, imageview, gesture, swipe-gesture

I managed to detect when I swipe a certain image. Now I want the image to "stretch" (like unlocking phone) when the user slides the image. Any way I can do this?

```
 image.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

}


class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.onDown(e);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Swipe2Activity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } 
            else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Swipe2Activity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply matrix transformations.

Here is a very good tutorial from Sony: http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android%E2%84%A2-application/

Comment: Thanks, but I want the image to stretch when the user swipes the image. Not sure how this tutorial helps....

Comment: It says how to resize the Bitmap on a Canvas, but you might want to just reuse this http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/

Comment: Or there is also this tutorial: http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/